# Image tag goes beyond parent on Chrome

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, material-ui

On Firefox, image gets resized and keep inside its container, but on Chrome it gets stuck on max width and overflow the container.

I'm using React with Material-ui. The image will be dynamic, the user will select from his device.

Is there any way to solve it with CSS?

[Example on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0lY2.png)

[Example on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h45gW.png)

The borders were added for clarification.

Code:

```html
.ImageInput-image-22 {
    max-width: 96px;
    max-height: 96px;
}

<div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-wrap-xs-nowrap MuiGrid-grid-xs-12">
    <div class="MuiGrid-root QuestaoEscolhaResposta-imageField-14 MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-sm-2">
        <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth">
            <label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-outlined" data-shrink="true" for="image-select-input"></label>
            <div class="ImageInput-root-16" style="border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;border-color: blue;">
                <input id="image-select-input" type="file" hidden="">
                <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root ImageInput-button-23 MuiIconButton-colorPrimary MuiIconButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button">
                    <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                        <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M19 7v2.99s-1.99.01-2 0V7h-3s.01-1.99 0-2h3V2h2v3h3v2h-3zm-3 4V8h-3V5H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h12c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-8h-3zM5 19l3-4 2 3 3-4 4 5H5z"></path></svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                </button>
                <img alt="Imagem selecionada" class="ImageInput-image-22" style="border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x100">
            </div>
            <p class="MuiFormHelperText-root MuiFormHelperText-contained"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="MuiGrid-root QuestaoEscolhaResposta-textField-15 MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-true" style="border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;border-color: red;">
        <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth">
            <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInput-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl MuiInputBase-marginDense MuiInput-marginDense">
                <input aria-invalid="false" name="descricao" placeholder="Resposta" required="" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputMarginDense MuiInput-inputMarginDense" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item">
        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-colorPrimary" tabindex="0" type="button" id="excluir-resposta">
            <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M14.59 8L12 10.59 9.41 8 8 9.41 10.59 12 8 14.59 9.41 16 12 13.41 14.59 16 16 14.59 13.41 12 16 9.41 14.59 8zM12 2C6.47 2 2 6.47 2 12s4.47 10 10 10 10-4.47 10-10S17.53 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z"></path></svg>
            </span>
            <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

I noticed that the browser was ignoring the size of the previous sibling of the image tag. If I let just the image, the size works as expected.
I used a workaround with CSS calc() to solve the problem temporarily, but it relies on the sibling size.

I just do not posted as an answer because would be nice to solve it properly.

```
.ImageInput-image-22 {
    max-width: 96px;
    max-height: 96px;
    width: calc(100% - 37px);
}
```

Comment: Try to decrease ```.ImageInput-image-22 {
    max-width: 96px; // 50px
    max-height: 96px; // 50px
}```. Then check if there’s any improvement. If there is, then keep increasing gradually till desired measurement. This will help to also find out why it’s different in Google Chrome.

Comment: @cd4success I have already done it. And seems that Chrome considers only max-width/height